# What is the difference between `storeid` and `userClassName`?

Tags: extjs, model, store

I'm reading about Sencha's `Store` [here](http://docs.sencha.com/architect/2/#!/guide/stores_models)

The two terms require unique name/id for it. Why do we need both of them? Why not just use `userClassName` value for `storeid`?

Answer (score 1):

The code to define a store is:

```
/**
 */
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Wallpaper', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.DirectStore',
    requires: [
        'MyModel'
    ],
    model: 'MyModel',
    constructor: function () {
        var me = this;
        var cfg = {
            storeId: 'wallpapersStore',
            proxy: {
                type: 'direct',
                directFn: mydirFn,
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'wallpapers'
                }
            }
        };
        me.callParent([cfg]);
        return me;
    }
});
```

In this definition the userClassName is actually: "MyApp.store.Wallpaper" and is used in

```
var instance1 = Ext.create('MyApp.store.Wallpaper');
```

While the storeId is used for global store instances:

```
var instance2 = Ext.getStore('wallpapersStore'); //instance1 === instance2
var instance3 = Ext.getStore('wallpapersStore'); //instance1 === instance2 === instance3
var instance4 = Ext.create('MyApp.store.Wallpaper'); //this generates an error because of the conflicting storeId's
```

Also, userClassName doesn't exist in ExtJS, it's only used by Sencha Architect to identify the className as wanted by the user;